# Es correcto decir la Empresa (nombre de la empresa)usando la palabra Empresa con mayúscula?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, sustantivos

Por ejemplo si quiero decir Informe de la Empresa "Los Pollitos" ¿estaría bien?, o la otra opción seria Informe de la empresa "Los Pollitos".
¿El sustantivo en ese caso es con mayúscula o minúscula¡

Agradeceré sus opiniones

Answer (score 4):

Si la palabra *empresa* forma parte del nombre "Empresa Los Pollitos", va en mayúsculas. Si solo se llama "Los Pollitos", la denominación va en minúsculas y admite ser reemplazada: establecimiento "Los Pollitos", compañía "Los Pollitos".

Answer (score 0):

Informe de la Empresa Los Pollitos

Tal y como se plantea la cuestión, la respuesta es no, puesto que la empresa no se llama "Empresa los Pollitos", solo "Los Pollitos".

Al inicio de frase, como cabecera o como título, "Informe de Los Pollitos", se sobrentiende que es una entidad que de por sí puede carácter jurídico.

---

La mayúscula distingue entre el nombre propio del nombre común, se podría utilizar en el inicio de la oración, después de un punto y aparte, comienzo de un párrafo, en el caso de que "empresa" reemplazara a un nombre propio, o si "Empresa" fuera la personificación que encarnara algo. Lo que si puedes hacer es escribirlas todas con mayúsculas como título a cabecera que de comienzo al informe en una hoja de inicio independiente o como título de una de las divisiones internas del informe.

---

Diccionario panhispánico de dudas

> mayúsculas. La escritura normal utiliza habitualmente las letras
> minúsculas, si bien, por distintos motivos, pueden escribirse
> enteramente con mayúsculas palabras, frases e incluso textos enteros
> (→ 2); pero lo usual es que las mayúsculas se utilicen solo en
> posición inicial de palabra, y su aparición está condicionada por
> distintos factores
>
> 2.2. Se utiliza la escritura en mayúsculas con el fin de destacar determinadas frases o palabras dentro de un escrito. Así, suelen
> escribirse enteramente en mayúsculas:

https://www.rae.es/dpd/may%C3%BAsculas

Answer (score 0):

El hecho de que aparezca el artículo "la" antes de "empresa" es indicativo de que "empresa" es un sustantivo común (que, por lo tanto, debería escribirse con minúscula inicial). Esta idea también se refuerza por la presencia de comillas solo para "Los Pollitos". Por lo tanto, la mayúscula en:

- Informe de la **E**mpresa "Los Pollitos"

parece ser una mayúscula de relevancia, y no una mayúscula requerida por la ortografía española.

Si "empresa" formara parte de la razón social, el título debería decir:

- Informe de Empresa Los Pollitos

En textos legales (ej. contratos), la palabra "empresa" se escribiría con mayúsculas si así fue definido al inicio:

> Este contrato se celebra entre la empresa "Los Pollitos" ("la Empresa") y la Sociedad de Crianza de Aves ("la Sociedad") ...
>
> La Empresa se compromete a informar a la Sociedad todas las ventas de pollitos que realice durante el año.

Alguien podría preguntarse por qué palabras como Sociedad, Dirección, Administración, etc. se escriben con mayúscula a pesar de llevar artículo (ej. **la S**ociedad de Crianza de Aves), y esto es así porque se trata de denominaciones de personas jurídicas diferentes de empresas.